# Adding a Boolean column into an existing table

Tags: mysql, alter

I'm trying to add a boolean column into an existing table

```
alter table chatuser add activerecord bool;
alter table chatuser add activerecord boolean;
```

where activerecord is my boolean column

Neither of these queries are working. How can I add a boolean column to an existing table?

Comment: Try to be more clear about which database software you're using--don't just use a tag.

Comment: [Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304942/2253682) using Android Room's SQLite library.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to define what you add - a column:

```
alter table chatuser  add column activerecord bool;
```

Answer (score 17):

Lack `COLUMN` keyword

```
ALTER TABLE ChatUser ADD COLUMN ActiveRecord TinyInt(1)
```

Comment: There is a bool data type. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html. These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`

Comment: BOOL and BOOLEAN are synonyms for TINYINT(1) in mysql.

Comment: `smallint` is actually kind of a waste. `tinyint` is smaller and totally sufficient for `bool`

Comment: @xdazz I was not aware of that. Thanks for the the info

Answer (score 14):

Add with default value

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN new_field TinyInt(1) DEFAULT 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE chatuser ADD activerecord BOOLEAN
```

No need of word 'column'

Your second query is perfectly all right (at least) in mysql.

Try:

```
select * from chatuser;
```

If you are unable to see results, check your mysql server or other things, not the
query and, if above select query works, and you do not have `activerecord`
named column already, I bet your query will work.

Answer (score 2):

I found that on Microsoft SQL the following was invalid:

```
ALTER TABLE meTable ADD COLUMN someBoolCol TinyInt;
```

Omitting the "column" keyword worked:

```
ALTER TABLE meTable ADD someBoolCol TinyInt;
```

Comment: Just so people are clear, OP asked about MySQL, not SQL in general. (Though they could have been more clear.)