# room migration using existing boolean column types

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

**What i found out so far**

All the @entity annotated classes are processed during compiletime and an Implementation for Database class is generated. Then before accessing the db, validateMigration method of this generated class is called. This validateMigration method verifies with the existing db schema via raw query

`PRAGMA table_info mytable name`

*(see L208 of android.arch.persistence.room.util.TableInfo.java)*

**Now the problem**

My sqlite3 db has some columns with column type as BOOLEAN. (which slqite internally handles to int). Now when i create room entities say

```
public someEntity {
     @columnInfo(name="someName")
     public Boolean myValue;
}
```

The room's create table query will be

`Create Table someEntity ( myValue INTEGER)`

Where as when we query the **existing** db with `PRAGMA table_info someEntity` we get

`1|myValue|BOOLEAN|0||0`

As explained above room verifies the ( sqlite to room ) migration by comparing field name, column type etc. And since the column types dont match (BOOLEAN and INTEGER) it throws an error saying migration failed.

Can anyone suggest a workaround to this ? Can we make room create BOOLEAN column type in sqlite ? (Also afaik we can't change/alter column types of existing tables.)

PS: I also see a similar issue with VARCHAR - [Using an existing VARCHAR column with Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664478/using-an-existing-varchar-column-with-room)

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71953987

Comment: Thanks for the link. I came across https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64822502 posted by you on the other question i mentioned. Looks like the issue has been there since august '17. Any workaround you can suggest other than creating a new table ? @CommonsWare

Comment: "Also afaik we can't change/alter column types of existing tables" -- you can create a temp table with your existing structure, copy the data to it, drop the real table, rebuild the real table with the Room-approved types, then copy the data back over. That's the only workaround that I know of at the present time.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am facing this issue with copying the data from sqlite to room table using migration. When I do not add not null to the create query inside migration, the create query and the entity with boolean/ int do not match and throwing error. If I add not null in the create query, I am getting error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:" . I have cross checked the old table and none of these columns have null value. They are all filled with either default values or inserted values. Any suggesstions what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @AshishKanswal: All that I can suggest is that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Define the migration for the new attribute *newAttribute* with both a `DEFAULT` value and as `NOT NULL`.

**Code**

`database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN newAttribute INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL")`

**Full Code**

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(ModelName::class), version = 2)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class DatabaseName : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun daoName(): DaoName

    companion object {

        private var INSTANCE: DatabaseName? = null

        fun getAppDatabase(context: Context): DatabaseName {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        DatabaseName::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .build()
            }
            return INSTANCE as DatabaseName
        }

        val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN newAttribute INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THE ANSWER :) SAVED ME A LOT OF TIME!

Comment: Can you please help me out to write default value inside entity class for Boolean property.

Answer (score 11):

SQLite does not have a boolean data type. Room maps it to an `INTEGER` column, mapping `true` to `1` and false to `0`.
I think below code would be work

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE xyz_table ADD COLUMN abc INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
```

It is undocumented.