# Migration not working in boolean value in Room Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I got it below mentioned exception

Migration didn't properly handle

```
Expected:
TableInfo{name='ContactModel', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
 number=Column{name='number', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, 
 isVerified=Column{name='isVerified', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
 age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

```
Found:
TableInfo{name='ContactModel', columns={number=Column{name='number', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, 
isVerified=Column{name='isVerified', type='Boolean', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
 name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
 age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Query

```
val migration2 = object : Migration(2, 3) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        val migString = "ALTER TABLE ContactModel ADD COLUMN isVerified Boolean"
        database.execSQL(migString)
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304942/2253682). The new boolean attribute migration must define a `DEFAULT` value and be set to `NON NULL`.

Comment: val migString = "ALTER TABLE ContactModel ADD COLUMN isVerified INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"             This query is working.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it looks like Room does not support Boolean, so your migration string should be:

```
val migString = "ALTER TABLE ContactModel ADD COLUMN isVerified INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"
```

and you can then use it as boolean in your code.